# How can I print sublists of a certain length?

Tags: python, list

I have a list with sublists in it. I want to print all the sublists with length equal to 3.

I am doing the following in python:

```
for x in values[:]:
    if len(x) == 3:
        print(x)
```

`values` is the original list. Does the above code print every sublist with length equal to 3 for each value of `x`? I want to display the sublists where `length == 3` only once.

The problem is solved. The problem is with the Eclipse editor. I don't understand the reason, but it is displaying only half of my list when I run my loop.

Are there any settings I have to change in Eclipse?

Comment: Could you do `print values` and show the output here?  *edit:* or just check that it's not blank.

Comment: I don't understand what is being asked here and how most of the answers relate to it. What does this have to do with Eclipse?!

Answer (score 206):

`x in mylist` is better and more readable than `x in mylist[:]` and your `len(x)` should be equal to `3`.

```
>>> mylist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7],[8,9,10]]
>>> for x in mylist:
...      if len(x)==3:
...        print x
...
[1, 2, 3]
[8, 9, 10]
```

or if you need more pythonic use [list-comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> [x for x in mylist if len(x)==3]
[[1, 2, 3], [8, 9, 10]]
>>>
```

Comment: Note: "your `len(x)` should be equal to `3`" is referring to an earlier revision of the question which had `len(x) == 2` as a mistake.

Answer (score 16):

You may as well use `for x in values` rather than `for x in values[:]`; the latter makes an unnecessary copy.  Also, of course that code checks for a length of 2 rather than of 3...

The code only prints one item per value of `x` - and `x` is iterating over the elements of `values`, which are the sublists.  So it will only print each sublist once.

Comment: values[:] slices out all the elements of values, right? I'm assuming that you meant the temporary list created from the slicing. Just want to make sure.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the unwanted copy. @batbrat it doesn't slices out, it slices off, what I mean is that the values are duplicated, and still in `values`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 15):

Here is the solution I was looking for.  If you would like to create List2 that contains the difference of the number elements in List1.

```
list1 = [12, 15, 22, 54, 21, 68, 9, 73, 81, 34, 45]
list2 = []
for i in range(1, len(list1)):
  change = list1[i] - list1[i-1]
  list2.append(change)
```

Note that while `len(list1)` is 11 (elements), `len(list2)` will only be 10 elements because we are starting our for loop from element with index 1 in list1 not from element with index 0 in list1

Comment: This was just what I needed as I needed to start from index 1 not 0.  +1

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
values = [[1,2,3],[4,5]]
for x in values:
    if len(x) == 3:
       print(x)
```

Comment: How is this any different than the top answer?