# Loops in Python3.6

Tags: python-3.6

I want to print a specified element from each list until it stops, however I am not sure of what loop conditions to use.

**Code**

[image]

For example, I have printed `element[0]` of each list but I want it to loop until it prints all the elements.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping over a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138112/looping-over-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The following code is, maybe, the simplest solution to print all the cats. If you want to print a single list, use only the last 2 lines after replacing "l" with your list variable.

```
a = ['Ginger', 'Lion', 'Persian', 'Sphynx']    
b = ['Mainecoon', 'Tiger', 'Ragdoll', 'Birman']
c = ['Lynx', 'Shorthair', 'Abyssinian', 'Scottishfold']
d = ['Ocelot', 'Jaguar', 'Chartreux', 'Korat']

lists = [a, b, c, d]
for l in lists:
    for cat in l:
        print(cat)
```